# Error: "missing ; before statement"

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple program to assist with answering a certain type of question i get for history homework. The code is meant to search through the question, find any *_*_s, and fill them in with your input for each one. I get a "missing ; before statement" error on line 5, however. Help?

```
var Que = prompt("Insert your completion question");
var Leng = Que.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= Leng; i+=1){
  if (Que.substring(i,i + 4) === "____"){
      var newword = prompt Que.substring(0, i + 4);
      Que.replace("____", newword);
      if (newword.length !== 4){
          var i = newword.length - 4 + i;
      }
  }
}
console.log(Que);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round your call to 'prompt' function with brackets at line 5:

```
var Que = prompt("Insert your completion question");
var Leng = Que.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= Leng; i+=1){
  if (Que.substring(i,i + 4) === "____"){
      var newword = prompt(Que.substring(0, i + 4));
      Que.replace("____", newword);
      if (newword.length !== 4){
          var i = newword.length - 4 + i;
      }
  }
}
console.log(Que);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the prompt call is missing ()

Change

```
prompt Que.substring(0, i + 4); 

to        

prompt(Que.substring(0, i + 4));
```